# Sharing very large objects between processes / threads from within a class?

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, shared-memory

I have a Python class from within which I want to spawn threads or processes to share data, without copying them across the threads or spawned processes. Here is an abstraction of what I am trying to do.

```
class ClassA(object):
  def work(self, bigDictionary, bigList):
      param1 = self.getDictParam(bigDictionary)
      param2 = self.getListParam(bigList)
      return self.someOtherWork(param1, param2)

  def parallelizeWork(self, listOfBigDictionaries, listOfBigLists):
      result = # PARALLEL WORK ON EACH PAIR OF DICTIONARY AND LIST
      return result
```

As you can realize my task (processor bound) is embarrassingly parallel, and I tried multi-processing. Unfortunately, because the objects I am passing are big, they trigger pickling errors. I really don't want the processes or threads to copy the data, as `work` and the functions it calls do not modify any of the objects; rather I would have them to simply read from the objects. Is there a proper way to do this in Python?

Comment: Is the *work* i/o bound or processor bound?

Comment: processor bound

Comment: What makes you think that the size of the objects are causing the pickling errors?  Did you read [Sharing state between processes](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) in the docs?

Comment: @wwii The error thrown literally said, cannot pickle objects over 2 GiB.

Comment: You probably need to give more information about how you are using the big shared object. But I think if you use multithreading instead of multiprocessing, it will avoid pickling and therefore work.

Comment: `bigList` and `bigDictionary` are 2+GB?, How about `param1` and `param2`.  Maybe you can have a single process that serves `getDictParam` and `getListParam` requests, that process holds the big things and the only communication between it and the worker processes are requests and responses through pipes or queues.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming we’re talking about CPython...

If you can do the compute work in a Python extension like `numpy` that knows how to yield the GIL, then using threads (as Will suggested) will work well.

Otherwise, on POSIX systems you can use `multiprocessing` with `fork` but no `exec`, which notionally avoids *physically* copying the data with COW forking.  However, the constant fiddling with reference counts performed by normal Python code gradually breaks the OS’s sharing between the copies of the process.  Even the deallocation of the data at the end of each process could easily balloon the memory required.  But if you have *large* objects (like long strings) rather than *many* objects (like long lists), it might be OK.

Comment: it is worth noting that instagram has done [some nice work](https://engineering.instagram.com/copy-on-write-friendly-python-garbage-collection-ad6ed5233ddf) on this topic.